# Navbar is not collapsing in bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, nav

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 and my navbar is not collapsing on smaller devices. Navbar does appear, but clicking on the `navbar-toggle` button does not bring any options up.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
        <div class="orange"><i class="fas fa-football-ball"></i> Fantasy</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="picks.html">Picks & Busts of the Week</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">Important Dates/Announcements</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Chat/Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: share the whole code, the output, the errors in the console, etc.

Comment: Are you loading the JS file correctly?

Comment: So you included JQuery, Boostrap js and Bootstrap CSS? Code seems fine when I ran it with those.

Comment: Making it a snipplet and adding `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
` seems to make it work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It does appear, but clicking on it does not bring any options up

The problem might be mainly due to the fact that you are not loading the required JavaScript files properly. You can grab the CDN via [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/). Don't forget to add the Jquery CDN since you are using version 3.3.7 and it is not mentioned properly in the documentation. . Add these `script` tags to your HTML

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Latest Jquery CDN-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a working example.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
        <div class="orange"><i class="fas fa-football-ball"></i> Fantasy</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="picks.html">Picks & Busts of the Week</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">Important Dates/Announcements</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Chat/Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!--Latest Jquery CDN -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Ah good call! I had the script src and all down but I had crossorigin="anonymous"></script> at the end of the cloudflare one. Once that was deleted, my dropdown has been working.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are using boostrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
```